# A basic question for quotient associative algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Suppose $R$ is a commutative ring, and $\mathfrak a$ is an ideal in $R$.

Let $A$ be an associative $R$-algebra. Then, let's consider a specific ideal in $A$, given by $I:= \mathfrak a \cdot A$ consisting of finite sums $\sum a_i x_i$ with $a_i\in \mathfrak a$ and $x_i\in A$.

Now, we can form the quotient $B:= A/ I$; it is an associative $R$-algebra as well. However, I've been told that this $B$ is actually also an associative $R/\mathfrak a$-algebra. Is this claim true?

Comment: If an $R$-algebra is annihilated by an ideal $K$ of $R$, then it is an $R/K$-algebra.